# Why there is need for an empty echo/print line in much CGI scripts?

Tags: python, bash

Why there is need for an empty echo/print line in much CGI scripts?

Example bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ''
echo 'CGI Bash Example'
```

Example python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print  

print "Hello World!"
```

Comment: I don't think your specific example doesn't portray the use of `echo ''`  if there are any at all.

Comment: When i remove that line in get a 500 internal server error. I use Apache.

Comment: See the section titled *"General format"* on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields